# QFile init/assignment op issue when objects are class members

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfile, qtextstream

So i have a QFile and QTextStream member as part of my class... trying to init. them together in my constructor:

**Class.h:**

```
QFile _file;
QTextStream _textstrm;
```

**Class.cpp:**

```
_file = QFile (/*file name*/);
_file.open(/*set stuff*/);
_textstrm = QTextTream ( &_file );
```

And the comp error i get, C2248, says the objects to have access to the operators in their own class..

Comment: what is ctor???

Comment: Ctor is short for constructor.

Comment: You could show more information, and the complete traceback.

Comment: Apologies, doing this thru the phone app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new object and you are adding an attribute that has no access, you must use the functions provided by the object.

```
_file.setFileName(/*file name*/);
_file.open(/*set stuff*/);
_textstrm.setDevice( &_file );
```